# How do I select distinct on more than one tag in InfluxDB

Tags: database, influxdb

I have a simple InfluxDB schema called SWPFND that looks like this:

```
time                base counter  prov_ticker        provider rate        source ticker        utc_received
----                ---- -------  -----------        -------- ----        ------ ------        ------------ 
1636761600000000000 USD  YFI      YFI-USD-SWAP       okex     0.00019687  HIST   USD-YFI       
1636761600000000000 USD  YFII     YFII-USD-SWAP      okex     -0.0001805  HIST   USD-YFII      
1636761600000000000 USD  ZEC      ZEC-USD-SWAP       okex     0.00026098  HIST   USD-ZEC       
1636761600000000000 USDT 1000SHIB 1000SHIBUSDT       Binance  0.00050791  HIST   USDT-1000SHIB 
1636761600000000000 USDT 1000XEC  1000XECUSDT        Binance  0.0001      HIST   USDT-1000XEC  
1636761600000000000 USDT 1INCH    1INCH-USDT-SWAP    okex     -0.00172767 HIST   USDT-1INCH    
1636761600000000000 USDT 1INCH    1INCHUSDT          Binance  -0.0007235  HIST   USDT-1INCH    
1636761600000000000 USDT AAVE     AAVE-USDT-SWAP     okex     0.00010114  HIST   USDT-AAVE     
1636761600000000000 USDT AAVE     AAVEUSDT           Binance  0.0001      HIST   USDT-AAVE     
.....
```

`rate` is a field, `time` is the timestamp, while everything else including `base` and `counter` are tags.

How can I select distinct on both `base` and `counter` at the same time.

In postgres I could `select distinct base, counter from SWPFND`, however in InfluxDB, first I have to contort things a bit to select distinct:

```
> select distinct(counter) from (select rate, counter from SWPFND) limit 5
name: SWPFND
time distinct
---- --------
0    1000SHIB
0    1000XEC
0    1INCH
0    AAVE
0    ADA
```

But also, it won't do distinct on more than one tag:

```
> select distinct(base, counter) from (select rate, base, counter from SWPFND) limit 5
ERR: distinct function can only have one argument
```

Is there any way to achieve this other than on client side? Please note that I prefer answers that do not require me to combine the two columns into a third one (on which I could select distinct) at ingest time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I have found a way to do it, though I'm open  to ideas on whether things can be done better.

```
> select distinct(base) from (select base, counter, rate from SWPFND) group by counter
name: SWPFND
tags: counter=1000SHIB
time distinct
---- --------
0    USDT

name: SWPFND
tags: counter=1000XEC
time distinct
---- --------
0    USDT

name: SWPFND
tags: counter=1INCH
time distinct
---- --------
0    USD
0    USDT
```

...

You can also group by more than one tag, delimited by commas:

```
> select distinct(provider) from (select rate, provider, base, counter from SWPFND) group by base, counter
name: SWPFND
tags: base=USD, counter=1INCH
time distinct
---- --------
0    okex
0    FTX

name: SWPFND
tags: base=USD, counter=AAVE
time distinct
---- --------
0    FTX

name: SWPFND
tags: base=USD, counter=ADA
time distinct
---- --------
0    okex
0    FTX

name: SWPFND
tags: base=USD, counter=ADAB
time distinct
---- --------
0    Binance

...
```